# How to make Bootstrap modal dialog mobile friendly

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, modal-dialog

I have the following modal dialog:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="theCoolestModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" ng-controller="theCoolestCtrl" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">

            <div class="modal-header">
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Terms of Use</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p ng-bind-html="policyText"></p>
                <br />
                <div class="checkbox">
                    <label><input type="checkbox" value="" ng-click="toggleChecked()">I acknowledge the Terms of Use</label>
                </div>
                <br />
                <br />
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-lg" disabled ng-if="!termsChecked">Accept Terms</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" ng-if="termsChecked" ng-click="acceptTermsOfUse(PersonIdentifier, escortPolicyId)">Accept Terms</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now, I've attempted to utilize the Bootstrap grid system, but to no avail. The modal dialog doesn't work well at all with a vertical phone size screen. This is a good size for everything bigger than that.

How can I make it dynamic, fitting a vertical (let's say iPhone 6) screen with everything in one column at that size?

Comment: Check this anser :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32960737/implementing-grid-system-in-bootstrap-modal-form/32961889#32961889